# Core Audio, Tempo, Beat, Events and InterApp Audio

Tags: core-audio, audiounit

I currently have an AUGraph consisting of several nodes, FilePlayers, mixers, effects, that finally output to an Output Node.

I've managed to get this to work with AudioBus on iOS.

Now I want to get this to work with Inter-App Audio, but I have a few questions I don't know the answer to.

How do I make my output node available on InterApp Audio, so that my app shows up in Garage Band.

Once connected to Garage Band, how do I respond to events such as play, record, reset... and how do I get the Tempo and Beat?

The closest I can find on getting the Tempo and Beat is a callback method called HostCallback_GetBeatAndTempo

I also see

HostCallback_GetMusicalTimeLocation
HostCallback_GetTransportState

Could also be the MIDICallbacks I see, but I'm not sure.

A description of these can be found in AudioUnitProperties.h, but its not quite clear how you'd actually go about using them. I'd assume you set the AURenderCallback,

My questions summarised

1. How do I make the output node of the app "discoverable" (I've done this for AudioBus but I don't know how to do it for Interapp-Audio)
2. Once connected, how do I make my app respond to events from GarageBand?
3. How do I get the Tempo and Beat from Garageband?

Comment: did you ever sorted this out ?